# In SQL Server, create a sequence that assigns same value for duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

The duplicates can be recognized based on different conditions. For example, in this table:

```
ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|ColumnD|DupSequence
```

if (ColA and ColC) are the same in two records or (ColA and ColB) is the same in two records, then they have the same value in DupSequence. Dupsequence is different for different combinations.

How can I do this in SQL Server?

EDIT

The logic is:

Record1.ColA=Record2.ColA AND Record1.ColC=Record2.ColC

OR

Record1.ColA=Record2.ColA and Record1.ColB=Record2.ColB

DupSequence is a numeric field. Those that satisfy above conditions would have the same number.

Comment: What if Column A, B, and C are the same? What if A and C are the same, and B and D are the same, but they're different from each other?

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried ROW_NUMBER OVER PARITION BY (...) but that doesn't allow me to do multiple OR conditions

Comment: `DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ColA, ColB ORDER BY Colc) AS DupSequence`

Comment: @Lamak Did you make a typo?

Comment: @user3808188 yeah, it was supposed to be `ColA, ColB`

Comment: I think we're going to need sample data and desired output, your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the "trick" is to select the conditions when updating:

```
Update table
   set DupSequence = 'True'
  from table t2
 where table.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA
   and (   table.ColumnB = T2.ColumnB
        or table.ColumnC = T2.ColumnC
       )
```

If you want to assign a unique DupSequence number .. that is a bit more difficult.

Comment: I'm sorry you've misunderstood the question. I'll try to edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: Can I do something like DupSequence=xyz.nextval, where "xyz" is a sequence? I don't have SQL Server experience so don't know if it is valid here or not..

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table
SET DupSequence = 1
FROM Table AS x
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 0 FROM Table AS y
    WHERE x.Id != y.Id -- whatever primary key you have here
    AND ((x.ColumnA = y.ColumnA
    AND x.ColumnC = y.ColumnC)
    OR (x.ColumnA = y.ColumnA
    AND x.ColumnB = y.ColumnB))
)
```